# how to update nvd3 pie chart and resize it

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

how can I update nvd3 pie chart with new values and also resize the pie chart based on its container size.

I already have line and bar chart working with this command to update the chart and also update on resize.

But for PIE chart it throws an error "update is not a function", please help!

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
```

Answer (score 0):

newbie bummer.

was using var chart = nv.models.pie()

should have been

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
```